# How do I test and run a local version of my Discord bot while it is hosted?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I recently hosted my first Discord bot on Heroku. I am trying to update it and make some changes, but I am only getting the hosted-bot's responses on Discord. I am using Node.js to run it locally for testing. Not sure how to run a local version that doesn't interfere with the hosted version. I am working on adding embeds and it is important to see the messages from the bot on Discord in testing. Might be a dumb question, but I am fairly confused on how to do this.

Comment: Where did you code the bot itself? Add changes to the source which was hosted to Heroku

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using discord.js, what you are actually programming is essentially just a set of functions that make using the discord API easier. For example, you could always use the discord API to send messages (or reactions and other interactions) to users without using discord.js, but that would be more difficult which is why we have libraries like discord.js.

Running tests using a local bot while your main bot is hosted would most likely be possible, but this could also have some unforeseen consequences depending on the actual function of the bot itself. Additionally, if you are using slash commands, you would have to register the new commands and this could mess with the hosted bot since Discord tries to alert users whenever slash commands are changed.

In summary, it very well may be possible to use a local bot even though you are hosting another version of that same bot already, but a much better option would be to either edit the source code of the bot which is being hosted, make another bot for testing purposes, or simply stop hosting the bot for a short period of time while doing tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can create a new AppId for the test bot. In that way, they won't interfere with each other.

Once testing has been completed, switch to the production AppId.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be to separate your bot's complex functions from the discord api using something like Dependency Injection or the Managed Effects pattern. Basically, instead of programming your bot with direct access to discord, you would program it with access to a set of action functions, like "send message" or "get user id". Then, you can write fake versions of those action functions, so that it sends a message by printing it to the console instead of sending it to the discord api, and where 'get user id' always returns zero, for instance.

For testing features like embeds, you would basically have to log the entire embed object, and manually check that it follows the structure of the embed object [as specified by Discord's official docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-limits).